# Как использовать транзакции при создании денежных операций?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

В своём приложении я храню финансовые операции пользователя в отдельной таблице (пополнения/траты). Текущий баланс пользователя рассчитывается на основе суммирования всех операций.

При совершении покупки проверяется текущий баланс и если он больше или равен сумме покупки - создается новая расходная операция.

Я переживаю за то, что при большой нагрузке (или просто при стечении обстоятельств) система сможет пропустить две покупки, даже если денег хватает только на одну. Баланс пользователя уйдет в минус, однако услуга будет получена.

Если бы баланс хранился просто полем, то я бы мог использовать select for update, но тут баланс каждый раз рассчитывается. Как использовать транзакции в данном случае?

Comment: *При совершении покупки проверяется текущий баланс и если он больше или равен сумме покупки - создается новая расходная операция.* Это явно лишняя операция. CHECK constraint сделает то же самое, но без дополнительных запросов. Заодно он же и не позволит создаться ситуации, когда *система сможет пропустить две покупки, даже если денег хватает только на одну* - потому что в принципе не позволит полю получить не отвечающее требованию значение, как бы там конкурентные запросы не изгалялись.

Comment: *Как использовать транзакции в данном случае?* Любая описанная операция предполагает как минимум две записи - запись покупки и запись продажи. Транзакция должна объединять эти две операции в атом - т.е. либо оба запроса выполнены успешно, либо оба запроса не выполнены.

Comment: @Akina как конкретно в данной ситуации поможет check constraint? В check constraint я не могу выполнить проверку и узнать, достаточно денег или нет.

Comment: Ммм... простите, а не хотите ли Вы сперва почитать, что это такое и как работает? ну просто чтобы ерунды не говорить...

Comment: @Akina носом ткните, пожалуйста, как в postgres можно добавить constraint, который будет выполнять подзапрос и узнавать текущий баланс с помощью него. Я искал, не нашел, поэтому пришел сюда за решением, а не за "ценным" советом погуглить

Comment: 1) В таблицу юзеров добавляете поле Баланс. 2) Накладываете на него ограничение, что значение неотрицательно. 3) Создаёте на таблице транзакций триггер, который по значению суммы транзакции и ИД юзера обновляет его баланс. Теперь при вставке записи об очередной транзакции триггер пробует обновить баланс. Если денег достаточно, операция обновления баланса выполняется, а транзакция записывается. Если денег мало, ограничение отвергает обновление баланса, транзакция не записывается, а программа получает соответствующее сообщение об ошибке. Всё. Параллельные процессы при этом не интерферируют.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, завел - работает